# Salesforce1 Canvas App stuck at loading

Tags: salesforce1-app, canvas

I've created a test Canvas App, hooked it up to an Action. It's a basic "hello world" App. It decodes the signed requests and prints "hello world". It works fine in Canvas App Previewer, however when I tap that action in Salesforce1 it's stuck at loading:
[image]

I've searched in logs on my server and I'm not getting any requests so I guess it's not getting past Salesforce platform. Any help appreciated.